# Application window focus on open

Tags: applications

Not sure if this is a known bug or not for Juno, but I was wondering if this could get patched (it would seem like an easy fix).

When I click on the applications menu with my mouse, then click on the app icon with my mouse, everything works as expected...

HOWEVER, when I type the name of the app and press enter, the application that opens IS NOT in focus, requiring me to Alt-Tab over to it first before I can begin typing/using it.

While it seems like a tiny thing it really disrupts my workflow since I try to use the mouse as little as possible.

I'd say its more of an oversight than anything, but is there any chance this can get fixed in the next patch?

Just to clarify, clicking works, using the arrow keys works, but typing the name of the app and hitting 'enter' to open it will not bring it in focus when launched.